# Can a cup of coffee be used as a barometer?

Tags: weather, divination

A recent [Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/Predict-weather-with-a-cup-of-coffee/#step1) was picked up by [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5896281/use-your-coffee-cup-as-a-basic-barometer). It states:

> When you pour the coffee into your cup, watch the bubbles.
>
> If the bubbles move to the edge of the cup rather quickly, that's a good sign. Expect clear skies for the next 12 hours.
>
> If the bubbles hang around in the center of the cup, get out your rain gear. You can expect rain in 12 hours.
>
> If the bubbles slowly move to the edge of the cup, you may get a bit of weather, but it should be clearing in a few hours.
>
> If you've managed to make a cup without bubbles, flop a spoonful of coffee back into your cup and make some more bubbles.

In the 'theory' section, they say:

> The theory behind this trick is that high pressure will push the bubbles to the edge, and high pressure indicates a period of sunny, calm weather. Low pressure won't move the bubbles and low pressure systems typically bring unsettled weather.

Is this true?

Comment: Unfortunately there are so many variables when making coffee I can't see this being true - temperature of water, type of coffee, concentration of coffee etc., and when combined with the frankly dubious "high pressure will push bubbles to the edge".... I'm thinking a big no.

Comment: +1 @RoryAlsop I was thinking on similar lines that this question, with small modifications could also qualify as a Physics SE question with ideal assumptions regarding the variables involved.

Comment: duplicate of: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74771/weather-forecasting-with-coffee-bubbles